# Can't install Clementine, dependency issue

Tags: 12.10, clementine

This is the message I get when trying to reinstall Clementine in the Ubuntu software centre. And I tried to reinstall the packages in synaptic package manager, but nothing helps... I am pretty lost in what to do next, cause I tried a lot of different solutions.

```
clementine: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
            Depends: libechonest1.2 (>= 1.2.0) but 1.2.1-1 is to be installed
            Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.34.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libmtp9 (>= 1.1.0) but 1.1.4-1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
            Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: libtag1c2a (>= 1.7) but 1.8-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
            Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13 is to be installed
            Depends: projectm-data (>= 2.0.1+dfsg-6) but 2.1.0+dfsg-1build1 is to be installed
```

Comment: try to Uninstall it and reinstall it again. type this command, "sudo apt-get remove --purge clementine* "

Answer (score 0):

I just tried installing it, and it worked.  Here is what I did.  I just just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

[image]

When it was done, I typed Clementine in dash, clicked on it, and it works.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty lost in what to do next, cause I tried a lot of different solutions.

It would be helpful to know these:

- the version of Ubuntu you have installed
- the mirror you use to download your packages
- what you tried before.